# Mockito get all mocked objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to get the list of all mocked objects. Using a previous version of Mockito I could do this:

```
List<Object> createdMocks = new LinkedList<Object>();
MockingProgress progress = new ThreadSafeMockingProgress();
progress.setListener(new CollectCreatedMocks(createdMocks));
```

These listeners are removed in the latest 2.8 version of Mockito, is there any alternative for it?

Comment: Specifically, these were removed in 2.0.80-beta. The `internal` package was described as "not to be used by clients". What's wrong with just maintaining a `List<Object>` yourself? Why do you need the framework to do it for you?

Comment: @Michael In case I plan to add a new dependency and mock it, i have to explicitly add it to the list. So adding a listener to get mocks for all my classes would help reduce the responsibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Mockito 2.x this has been replaced by implementations of `org.mockito.listeners.MockitoListener` which you engage like so:

```
Mockito.framework().addListener()
```

For example:

```
@Test
public void listAllMocks() {
    List<Object> mocks = new ArrayList<>();

    // can be replaced by a lambda if using java 8+
    Mockito.framework().addListener(new MockCreationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMockCreated(Object mock, MockCreationSettings settings) {
            mocks.add(mock);
        }
    });

    A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
    B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);

    // ... do something with a, b

    // verify
    assertThat(mocks.size(), is(2));
    assertThat(mocks, hasItem(a));
    assertThat(mocks, hasItem(b));
}
```

Comment: one liner with lambda expression

```java
List<Object> mocks = new ArrayList<>();
Mockito.framework().addListener((MockCreationListener) (mock, settings) -> mocks.add(mock));
```

Comment: @qoomon Removing newlines doesn't make something a "one liner", it only makes the code less readable.